# Why does SCNNode .flattenedClone() either crash or make performance worse?

Tags: performance, scenekit, scnnode, scngeometry

I'm attempting to add around 4.5k `SCNNode` objects to a scene. Their geometries are one of two `SCNPlane`s, whose materials are rendered by `CALayer`s (but I don't think that matters, the `CALayerDelegate`s are only called once each, so that doesn't seem to be an issue.) Performance is terrible (< 1fps.)

With `.showsStatistics` enabled I see I'm doing almost 3.5k draw calls, which is my problem according to [this WWDC video from 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-605/?time=1187). So, as suggested, I add all my nodes to one parent node and call `.flattenedClone()` on it before adding that to the scene's root node. That gets me graphical corruption and a repeating error on my console:

```
2019-08-28 14:50:39.122937+0200 Breadboard[867:53252] [SceneKit] Error: C3DProgramHashCodeStoreRegisterProgramForRendererElement - index out of capacity (8192 > 8192)
```

(The x in "x > 8192" goes up by one every line)

If I split the nodes into two groups and call `.flattenedClone()` on them before adding the results to the root node the error goes away but my draw call count *goes up* to almost 5k!

What's going on? Why does calling `.flattenedClone()` on a node with around 2.5k nodes not... flatten it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem *did* turn out to be the `CALayer`s, but it's subtle: if I instead render the `CALayer` into a `UIImage` (actually I do it all as a `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(...)`, there's no need for an explicit `CALayer`), `.flattenedClone()` does indeed do what I expect it to do and I get close to 60fps with any number of cells. If I attach the `CALayer` directly to the material, the nodes don't flatten.

Maybe it's something to do with the fact a `CALayer` is animatable? In any case, with static `UIImage` it works. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898979/scnnode-flattenedclone-does-not-reduce-draw-calls) gave me the hint by mentioning some cases where flattening is automatic, and some where it doesn't happen at all even if you invoke it.